# Creating a tmux session without attaching to it

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to create a new `tmux` session without attaching to it. Running `man tmux` shows nothing for this, but there must be someway to do this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can run

```
tmux new-session -d
```

to start the new session in detached mode.

```
$ tmux list-sessions
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
$ tmux new-session -d
$ tmux list-sessions 
0: 1 windows (created Sun Aug 21 16:18:46 2016) [80x23]
```

You can run specific commands eg

```
tmux new-session -d vi
```

would run `vi` in the new session, but detached.

```
$ ps -ef | grep -w vi   
sweh      2313  1906  0 16:20 pts/2    00:00:00 grep -w vi
$ tmux new-session -d vi
$ ps -ef | grep -w vi   
sweh      2317     1  0 16:20 ?        00:00:00 tmux new-session -d vi
sweh      2318  2317  0 16:20 pts/3    00:00:00 vi
sweh      2320  1906  0 16:20 pts/2    00:00:00 grep -w vi
```

Sessions can be named by specifying the `-s` flag after the `-d`

```
$ tmux new-session -d -s foobar          
$ tmux list-sessions
foobar: 1 windows (created Sun Aug 21 16:27:10 2016) [80x23]

$ tmux attach-session -t foobar
```

Comment: What about being able to name that session? I tried: `tmux new -s {name} -d` and that didn't work.

Comment: @innectic Looks like `tmux new -d -s <name>` works

Comment: @innectic See updated answer